# Drupal nested json not working in Sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, drupal-views

My json format

```
 Ext.data.JsonP.callback3({"nodes":[
 {"node":{"title":"Dane Sample Name - Owner/Stylist/Daymaker","field_headshot":"","body":"Born and raised in Carencro, La., Dane knew from a young age that he wanted to become a successful hairdresser. \n","nothing":""}},

 {"node":{"title":"Rahul - Owner/Stylist/Daymaker","field_headshot":"","body":"Since 1995 Jeanne has enjoyed helping people to feel and look beautiful.\n","nothing":""}}]})
```

Models

```
Ext.define('SampleApp.model.Drupal', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
 uses: [
    'SampleApp.model.Drupal2'
],
config: {
        fields : [ 
            'node'
        ],

},   
 hasMany: {
         model: 'Drupal2',
         name  : 'node',
         associationKey: 'node' ,
      }    
 });

Ext.define('SampleApp.model.Drupal2', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',


    config: {
        fields: [
            'title','body'
        ]}     
});
```

Store

```
Ext.define('SampleApp.store.DrupalStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
requires: [ 
    'SampleApp.model.Drupal2'],

config: {
    autoLoad : true,
    model: 'SampleApp.model.Drupal2',
    proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url: 'data/data.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'nodes.node'
        }
    }
}
});
```

The above is the nested json from drupal view and I am trying to use those 2 models and store to load list in my view.I am trying to add list of titles from node but List is not loading in the view.If I give root property as nodes then it is loading all the data but not mapping to node.Please help me on where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed my Model, it is not using associations.Here is the Model that worked for me

```
 Ext.define('SampleApp.model.Drupal', {
 extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
   config: {
        fields: [
              {
            name: 'title',
            mapping: 'node.title', // mapping worked

        },
        {
            name: 'field_headshot',
            mapping : 'node.field_headshot',

        },
        {
            name: 'body',
            mapping : 'node.body',
        }
        ],
    }
 });
```